# Delete element from a nested list while keeping the original nested structure CLISP

Tags: lisp, clisp

Is there a way to delete an element from a nested list while also keeping the nested structure intact?

For instance, for the list `((1 (2 (3 (3 4 5 (3 (3)))) 3 4) 3 3) 3 (3 3))` if we delete the element `3` then the result should be `((1 (2 ((4 5 (()))) 4)) ())`, essentially the function should keep the previous list structure

I tried checking 3 cases:

**a)** if the current element is an atom and equal to the given number, then nothing should happen

**b)** if the current element is an atom and different than the given number, then it should be appended to the result

**c)** if the current element is a list, then the delete function should be applied to it (using `mapcar` and a `lambda`)

If I run my delete function on the list `((1 (2 (3 (3 4 5 (3 (3)))) 3 4) 3 3) 3 (3 3))` where the given number is `3`, it outputs `(1 2 4 5 4)` instead of the expected outcome `((1 (2 ((4 5 (()))) 4)) ())`

I believe it's because I turn the current element into a list (if it's equal to the given number) and then use `append` which removes the parentheses

```lisp
(defun delete (no l)
    (cond
        ;; current element == given number
        ;; it shouldn't be added to the result -> nil
        ((and (atom l) (equal no l)) nil)
        ;; current element != given number
        ;; it is made into a list and added to the result
        ((and (atom l) (not (equal no l)))  (list l))
        ;; current element is a list
        ;; the delete function is applied to each element of the list using mapcar
        (t (apply 'append (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (delete n x)) l)))))
```